# Why the class type changes when using virtual function?

Tags: c++

I'd like to know why the class type is changed in using string and virtual function.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
 
class Base {
public:
    std::string str;
    virtual void vvfunc() {};
};
 
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void vvfunc() {}
};
 
using namespace std;
int main() {
   Derived* pd = new Derived;
   Derived* pd2 = pd;
   cout<<&pd<<endl;
   cout<<&pd2<<endl;
   cout << typeid( pd ).name() << endl;
   cout << typeid( *pd ).name() << endl;
   cout << typeid( pd2 ).name() << endl;
   cout << typeid( *pd2 ).name() << endl;
   delete pd;
   cout << typeid( pd2 ).name() << endl;
   cout << typeid( *pd2 ).name() << endl;
}
```

output

```
0x7ffeeaadd8f0
0x7ffeeaadd8d8
P7Derived
7Derived
P7Derived
7Derived
P7Derived
4Base
```

And when I don't use 'virtual', then I can get the class type that I want.(or not using string in the class, that makes same output)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class Base {
public:
    std::string str;
    void vvfunc() {};
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void vvfunc() {}
};

using namespace std;
int main() {
   Derived* pd = new Derived;
   Derived* pd2 = pd;
   cout<<&pd<<endl;
   cout<<&pd2<<endl;
   cout << typeid( pd ).name() << endl;
   cout << typeid( *pd ).name() << endl;
   cout << typeid( pd2 ).name() << endl;
   cout << typeid( *pd2 ).name() << endl;
   delete pd;
   cout << typeid( pd2 ).name() << endl;
   cout << typeid( *pd2 ).name() << endl;
}
```

output

```
0x7ffeec60e790
0x7ffeec60e778
P7Derived
7Derived
P7Derived
7Derived
P7Derived
7Derived
```

Can anybody please explain why this happens?

Comment: Since `pd2` has the same value as `pd`, dereferencing `pd2` after `delete pd;` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: You may not dereference a pointer if an object it pointed to no longer exist. Do you understand that both `pd` and `pd2` pointers point to the same object? You may check by printing the address of this object: `&*pd` and `&*pd2` (now, you are printing the addresses of the pointers themselves, which are different).

Comment: The program gives segmentation fault because, you have deleted the object and then dereferring it. But I don't get the same output as you have got in my g++ compiler. Can you please change the compiler and recheck if the output is same?

Comment: I used clang++(Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)).


Thank you everyone for answer to my question.


And I understand that the code after `delete` is wrong and my compiler had wrong behavior.